# What is this item I found on a quest?

Tags: fallout-shelter

I found something unusual on a *Red Rocket Reveal!* quest - like a small hovering icon or item with flame-like glow. Nothing happens when I tap it, and I was afraid to miss it if I finished the quest ;-) Any clues?[image: low resolution on Android. The item in the circle]

Comment: Red Rocket is just a Legendary BB Gun. Are you sure you would ever want it?

Answer (score 7):

Were you just defeating a "boss" raider? If so, it looks like a nuke grenade that he must have thrown when you killed him. It's probably just glitch.

Comment: Those are actually nuke grenades. @Ben

Comment: @Ben Look at the original un-edited version, and I think you'll get your answer.